# Minikube files do not persist after restart

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I'm using `minikube` version 0.28.0 and files don't persist after a restart.

I ran into the problem after noticing my database data disappears after a restart (even though the pods, `pv`'s, and `pvc`'s say they've been up for days). I used `minikube ssh` to create some files and noticed those disappear, too.

FWIW - I ran `minikube addons list` to confirm that `default-storageclass` is enabled

Should I be using `minikube --mount` to mount my data to my dev machine's disk? How can I persist my pods' data?

Answer (score 1):

According to the official [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/learning-environment/minikube/#persistent-volumes) `minikube` persists the data stored in the following host directories that can be mapped inside the particular PV via [hostPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath) volume type:

- /data
- /var/lib/minikube
- /var/lib/docker

Hence, in order to mount some custom host folder inside `minikube` VM, keeping the relevant data to retain across cluster reboots, you can use `minikube mount` command:

`minikube mount [flags] <source directory>:<target directory>`